# Установка драйвера для Alfa AWUS036NH

Tags: linux, wifi, makefile, kali-linux

Не получается установить драйвера для адаптера. 
Когда запускаю команду `make` в конце выполнения команды в терминале выводятся след. ошибки:

```
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[4]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-kali5-common/scripts/Makefile.build:309: /root/Загрузки/2011_0719_RT3070_RT3370_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o] Ошибка 1
make[3]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-kali5-common/Makefile:1539: _module_/root/Загрузки/2011_0719_RT3070_RT3370_RT5370_RT5372_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO/os/linux] Ошибка 2
make[2]: *** [Makefile:146: sub-make] Ошибка 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:8: all] Ошибка 2
make[1]: выход из каталога «/usr/src/linux-headers-4.19.0-kali5-amd64»
make: *** [Makefile:357: LINUX] Ошибка 2
```

wifi адаптера: Alfa AWUS036NH
OS: Kali Linux

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь [DKMS](https://habr.com/ru/post/266399/). `dkms.conf` и `Makefile` уже должны быть в исходниках модуля, т.ч. их не надо создавать, скорее всего.

---

Либо:

Ваши исходники находятся в каталоге с русским названием `Загрузки`. Переместите в `/usr/src`.

Перед ошибкой были предупреждения, какие именно?